Yahoo Finance Prices Not Returned to Excel vba 'CreateObject' Request
I can no longer get share prices etc. returned from Yahoo Finance to Excel.  My code returned all data successfully until a few days ago.
Now nothing is returned.  All that is returned is a message saying content is not currently available (this is shown below).
(If I create the url manually and click it, the correct webpage appears in the browser.)
I am running this from the UK.  I have tried various VPN location too without success.
Can someone please help???


<html><meta charset='utf-8'><script>if(window!=window.top){document.write('<p>Content is currently unavailable.</p><img src="//geo.yahoo.com/p?s=1197757039&t='+new Date().getTime()+'&_R='+encodeURIComponent(document.referrer)+'&err=404&err_url='+'https%3A%2F%2Fbrb.yahoo.net%3A443%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fdesktop%2Fquote%2FBATS.L%2Fanalysis%2Findex.html'+'" width="0px" height="0px"/>');}else{window.location.replace('https://www.yahoo.com/?err=404&err_url=https%3A%2F%2Fbrb.yahoo.net%3A443%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fdesktop%2Fquote%2FBATS.L%2Fanalysis%2Findex.html');}</script><noscript><META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='https://www.yahoo.com/?err=404&err_url=https%3A%2F%2Fbrb.yahoo.net%3A443%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fdesktop%2Fquote%2FBATS.L%2Fanalysis%2Findex.html'"></noscript></html>



My code is here:
Sub SharePrices()

    Dim sResp$, sHigh$, currentPrice$
    Dim analystNum$, sLow$, tMeanprice$
    Dim recMean$, recKey$
    Dim sSStatus$
    Dim Ticker As String
    Const SPAT = "\\"":{\\""raw\\"":([\d.]+),"
    Const SPATrec = "\\"":\\""(.*?)\\"","
    
    Ticker = ActiveCell.Value

    Url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & Ticker & "/analysis/?p=" & Ticker

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        sResp = .responseText
    End With
    
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "currentPrice" & SPAT
        If .Execute(sResp).Count > 0 Then
            currentPrice = .Execute(sResp)(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If
        .Pattern = "numberOfAnalystOpinions" & SPAT
        If .Execute(sResp).Count > 0 Then
            analystNum = .Execute(sResp)(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If
        .Pattern = "targetMeanPrice" & SPAT
        If .Execute(sResp).Count > 0 Then
            tMeanprice = .Execute(sResp)(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If
        .Pattern = "targetLowPrice" & SPAT
        If .Execute(sResp).Count > 0 Then
            sLow = .Execute(sResp)(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If
        .Pattern = "targetHighPrice" & SPAT
        If .Execute(sResp).Count > 0 Then
            sHigh = .Execute(sResp)(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If
        .Pattern = "recommendationMean" & SPAT
        If .Execute(sResp).Count > 0 Then
            recMean = .Execute(sResp)(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If
        .Pattern = "recommendationKey" & SPATrec
        If .Execute(sResp).Count > 0 Then
            recKey = .Execute(sResp)(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If
    End With

        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = currentPrice
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = analystNum
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = tMeanprice
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = sLow
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = sHigh
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = recMean
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = recKey
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = sResp
        
        currentPrice = ""
        analystNum = ""
        tMeanprice = ""
        sLow = ""
        sHigh = ""
        recMean = ""
        recKey = ""
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -8).Select
    Ticker = ActiveCell.Value
    
End Sub


Your approach is no longer supported by the site.  Check recent posts on this topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bVBA%5d%20yahoo&searchOn=3

@TimWilliams - strangely, the code works today...
